# TSQL search exact match into a string

Tags: sql-server, regex, string, t-sql, replace

I stumbling on an issue with string parsing; what I'm trying to achieve is substitute a marker string with a value but the string match needs to be perfect.

Keep in mind that before the compare I split the entire string in a table (rowID int, segment nvarchar(max)) wherever i find a space so, a thing like 'The delta_s is §delta_s' will look like:

> rowID | segment
>
> 1    |   the
>
> 2    |   deltaT_s
>
> 3    |   is
>
> 4    |   §deltaT_s

After this i cycle each row with my table of "replacements" (idString nvarchar(max), val float); example:

> Marker string (@segment): '§deltaT_s'
>
> String to replace (@idString): '§deltaT_s'

The instruction I am using (since "like" is a lost cause as far I can see):

```
SELECT STUFF(@segment, PATINDEX('%'+@idString+'[^a-z]%', @segment), LEN(@idString), CAST(@val AS NVARCHAR(MAX)))
```

with @val being the number to substitute taken from the "replacements" table.

Now, in my table of "replacements" i have 2 delta like markers

> 1) §deltaT_s
>
> 2) §deltaT

My issue is that when the cycle start comparing the segments with the markers and the §deltaT comes up it will substitute the first part of the string in this way

> '§deltaT_s' -> '10_s'

I don't understand what I am doing wrong with the REGEX anyone can give me and hand on this matter?

I am available in case more info are required.

Thank you,
F.

Comment: I'm confused. If you've split the string word by word, why not just compare with `=`?

Comment: Because it can occur that the string can also be something like this "the deltaT_s is §deltaT_s, see ya!" (with the comma next to the marker word). When the split occurs i will have a segment like such '§deltaT_s,' where the normal compare doesn't work (afaik). If there is a workaround please enlighten me. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use REPLACE? Example: SELECT REPLACE(@segment,@idString,CAST(@val as NVARCHAR(MAX))

Comment: @Martin K., because it will happen the same thing described before:
ex segment = '§deltaT_s', idString = '§deltaT' result: '10_s' (with val as 10); second cycle will go segment = '§deltaT_s', idString = '§deltaT_s' result: '10'.
Final result (concatenate): '10_s 10'

Comment: Thinking about it, in a string '§deltaT_s' replacing '§deltaT' by 10 will result in '10_s', i guess that's pretty normal. If you really have this §deltaT marker you should thinking about renaming it.

Comment: Why don't you put the marker at both begin and end of the token? Like `§deltaT_s§`, that will make everything easier

Comment: @Serpiton can you make an example please?

Comment: `4 | §deltaT_s§` instead of `4 | §deltaT_s` with that there will be no match with `§deltaT` 'cause there will be `§deltaT§` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible you should change the marking style putting a paragraph symbol (`§`) at both side of the token, making one of the example in your comment

```
the deltaT_s is §deltaT_s§, see ya!
```

doing that the sentence will be split as

```
rowID | segment
--------------------
    1 | the
    2 | deltaT_s
    3 | is
    4 | §deltaT_s§,
    5 | see
    6 | ya!
```

if the replace values are stored in a fact table you will have something like

```
token      | value
------------------
§deltaT§   | foo
§deltaT_s§ | 10
```

or you can fake it putting the symbol at the end of the token in you query.

Than it's possible to search for the substitution with a `LIKE` and a `LEFT JOIN` between the two tables

```
SELECT COALESCE(REPLACE(segment, t.token, t.value), segment) Replaced
FROM   Sentence s
       LEFT JOIN Token t ON s.segment LIKE '%' + t.token + '%'
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/108e3/4)</kbd>

If you cannot change the fact table you can fake the change adding the symbol after the token

```
SELECT COALESCE(REPLACE(segment, t.token, t.value), segment) Replaced
FROM   Sentence s
       LEFT JOIN Token t ON s.segment LIKE '%' + t.token + '§%'
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but this was a nice touch, avoiding me the REGEX.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not an option, but for me helped ones.

If you can use Regex in sql or create CLR functions, look at this link http://www.sqllion.com/2010/12/pattern-matching-regex-in-t-sql/ last 2 options.

For you the best will be to take last choice using CLR function.

Then you will can do like this:

Text: `the deltaT_s is §delta, see ya!`

Regex: `(?<=[^a-z])§delta(?![a-z_])` - this `(?<=[^a-z])` means  that will not take to match and `(?![a-z_])` is not followed by letters and underline.

Replace to : 10

I also have tried regex `\b§delta\b` (\b :Start or End of word), but it seems it doesn't like `§`